# Need an ORACLE SQL query to get distinct combination of values

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help on this query :(

```
COL X   COL Y
1       A
1       B
1       C
2       A
2       B
2       C
3       A
3       B
3       C
```

The output should be

```
COL X  COL Y
1       A or B or C
```

If 1 picks A ,
Then 2 Should not pick A (It can pick B or C) ,
If 2 Picks B then 3 should not pick B.

The out put should be like

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
```

or

```
1 C
2 A
3 B
```

or

...

Comment: the post is poorly formatted and difficult to read. You can use Ctrl+K to format code parts for readability

Comment: There are `A`, `B` and `C` for each and every `X` -- or are some variations possible (say `3A`, `3B`  but no `3C` ?)

Answer (score 1):

My first post here but I'll answer using a postgres db answer.

```
select 
  col1,
  col2
from
 (select row_number() over() rn1 , col1 from sample1 group by 2)a
inner join 
 (select row_number() over() rn2, col2 from sample1 group by 2)b
on a.rn1 = b.rn2
order by 1;
```

This returns the result set per your specification.

Comment: Thank for the post .But I am getting this error.ORA-30485: missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification
30485. 00000 -  "missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification"
*Cause:    Either the ORDER BY expression is mandatory for this function, or
           there is an aggregation group without any ORDER by expression.
*Action:
Error at Line: 92 Column: 10

Comment: You can see what I'm doing here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e8a0b/2  note that different databases have requirements for syntax.  I'm using postgres in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a distinct value for column `B` and an arbitrary value for `A`, then you can do:

```
select MIN(A), B
from table t
group by B;
```

If you actually want distinct values for both A and B, then learn a bit about [bipartite graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph).  This is, in particular, the matching algorithm.  I don't know if there is a non-recursive way to find such a set in SQL.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.But your query does not work, it gives 1 A,1 B,1 C    :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data are somehow "fixed", you can build *all* combinations using a `CROSS JOIN`. The query is rather complicated because of your sub-optimal data representation:

```
SELECT t1."COL X" as x1, t1."COL Y" as y1,
       t2."COL X" as x2, t2."COL Y" as y2,
       t3."COL X" as x3, t3."COL Y" as y3
FROM T t1 CROSS JOIN T t2 CROSS JOIN T t3
WHERE t1."COL Y" <> t2."COL Y"
  AND t1."COL X" <> t2."COL X"
  AND t2."COL Y" <> t3."COL Y"
  AND t2."COL X" <> t3."COL X"
  AND t3."COL Y" <> t1."COL Y"
  AND t3."COL X" <> t1."COL X";
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9bc0c/4

Answer (score 0):

try this in MYSQL :

```
set @rank:=1;
select n.X,n.Y from
(select a.SN as SN1,b.SN as SN2,a.X as X,a.Y as Y,(case when a.X=b.X then @rank:=@rank+1 else       @rank:=1 end) as ra from
(select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as SN,X,Y from temp,(select @rownum:=0) r)a left outer join
(select @rownum1:=@rownum1+1 as SN,X,Y from temp,(select @rownum1:=0) s)b
on a.SN-1=b.SN) n
where n.X=n.ra;
```